# Fill NaN in a column by mathematical operation of the other columns by detecting where the NaN occur

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe contains hundreds of columns. Luckily, they can be classified into two big groups with regular column names. Group 1 contains columns Pdc, Pdc.1, Pdc.2 .... Pdc.250. Group 2 consists of Pac, Pac.1., Pac.2 .... Pac.250. Please note that the first column from each group contains no suffix number.

I want to fill all NaN, wherever they are, using the following rule:
NaN in any row of a column from Group 1 (target column and row) is to be filled with the value from a column in Group 2 with the same order (source column and row) times the mean of the target column divided by the mean of the source column.

To make it simple, for example, if NaN is in Pdc.25 row 10 (Group 1), it should be filled by:
Pdc.25 row 10 = Pac.25 row 10 * (mean Pdc.25 / mean Pac.25)

If NaN is in Group 2, here is the formula:
Pac.30 row 15 = Pdc.30 row 15 * (mean Pac.30 / mean Pdc.30)

I write the following codes:

```
df['Pdc.25'] = (df['Pdc.25'].fillna(df['Pac.25']*((df['Pdc.25'].mean()/df['Pac.25'].mean())))).to_frame()
df['Pac.30'] = (df['Pac.30'].fillna(df['Pdc.30']*((df['Pac.30'].mean()/df['Pdc.30'].mean())))).to_frame()
```

The above codes work perfectly, but for 500 columns, I must write 500 lines of equations.

Any idea of how to make it simple, for example, by locating NaNs automatically and fill them according to the rule?

Thanks for looking at my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure columns are sorted and use `.values` to align the operations, given your naming conventions. Can use `.where` to fill everything. If you want to be safer in the case of missing columns (i.e. you have Pac.31 but not Pdc.31), then map the column names for the operations so alignment is guaranteed.

```
import pandas as pd
#df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

pac = df.filter(like='Pac')
pdc = df.filter(like='Pdc')

df_res = pd.concat([pac.where(pac.notnull(), pdc.multiply(pac.mean().div(pdc.mean().values).values).values),
                    pdc.where(pdc.notnull(), pac.multiply(pdc.mean().div(pac.mean().values).values).values)
                    ], axis=1)
```

#### Output `df_res`:

```
        Pac  Pac.1     Pac.2       Pdc     Pdc.1  Pdc.2
0  1.000000    6.0  3.000000  1.285714  4.952381    2.0
1  1.555556    1.0  2.000000  2.000000  2.000000    1.0
2  7.000000    6.0  3.714286  7.000000  4.952381    3.0
3  6.000000    7.0  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000    7.0
4  5.000000    2.0  3.714286  6.000000  1.650794    3.0
5  2.000000    7.0  4.000000  7.000000  5.000000    1.0
6  3.000000    4.0  3.000000  4.000000  1.000000    1.0
7  1.000000    5.0  3.000000  1.285714  7.000000    3.0
8  5.000000    5.0  6.000000  4.000000  5.000000    6.0
9  5.000000    2.0  3.714286  6.428571  1.000000    3.0
```

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7, np.NaN], (10,6)),
                  columns = ['Pdc', 'Pdc.1', 'Pdc.2', 'Pac', 'Pac.1', 'Pac.2'])

   Pdc  Pdc.1  Pdc.2  Pac  Pac.1  Pac.2
0  NaN    NaN    2.0  1.0    6.0    3.0
1  2.0    2.0    1.0  NaN    1.0    2.0
2  7.0    NaN    3.0  7.0    6.0    NaN
3  5.0    5.0    7.0  6.0    7.0    5.0
4  6.0    NaN    3.0  5.0    2.0    NaN
5  7.0    5.0    1.0  2.0    7.0    4.0
6  4.0    1.0    1.0  3.0    4.0    3.0
7  NaN    7.0    3.0  1.0    5.0    3.0
8  4.0    5.0    6.0  5.0    5.0    6.0
9  NaN    1.0    3.0  5.0    2.0    NaN
```

---

#### Explanation:

The first step is to sort the columns and then filter looking for columns that begin with the string `'Pac'` or `'Pdc'`. Since we sorted the index, this guarantees the ordering is consistent (so long as the set of suffixes in groups are identical)

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
pac = df.filter(like='Pac')
pdc = df.filter(like='Pdc')

print(pac.head(3))
#   Pac  Pac.1  Pac.2
#0  1.0    6.0    3.0
#1  NaN    1.0    2.0
#2  7.0    6.0    NaN

print(pdc.head(3))
#   Pdc  Pdc.1  Pdc.2
#0  NaN    NaN    2.0
#1  2.0    2.0    1.0
#2  7.0    NaN    3.0
```

Now we can do the math. Ignore the `.fillna` logic and just consider calculating what we would fill with for **everything**. `DataFrame` operations align on the Indices (**both** rows and columns). You can see that `pac` and `pdc` share the row Index, but the column Index (column names) are different, which causes an issue:

```
pac.mean()
#Pac      3.888889
#Pac.1    4.500000
#Pac.2    3.714286
#dtype: float64

pdc.mean()
#Pdc      5.000000
#Pdc.1    3.714286
#Pdc.2    3.000000
#dtype: float64

pac.mean().div(pdc.mean())
#Pac     NaN
#Pac.1   NaN
#Pac.2   NaN
#Pdc     NaN
#Pdc.1   NaN
#Pdc.2   NaN
```

However, because we previously sorted, we can see that the `values` are aligned, so instead we safely divide each columns mean accessing the values array. This gives the mean of each `Pac` column divided by the mean of the corresponding `Pdc` column.

```
pac.mean().div(pdc.mean().values)
#Pac      0.777778
#Pac.1    1.211538
#Pac.2    1.238095
#dtype: float64
```

Multipliation has the same alignment issue, so again access the values and now this gives us a `DataFrame`, the same shape as subsets, with what we should fill with if the value is null:

```
pdc.multiply(pac.mean().div(pdc.mean().values).values)
#        Pdc     Pdc.1     Pdc.2
#0       NaN       NaN  2.476190
#1  1.555556  2.423077  1.238095
#...
```

Finally, the `fillna` logic is accomplished with `where` because we have two `DataFrames`:

```
pac.where(pac.notnull(), pdc.multiply(pac.mean().div(pdc.mean().values).values).values)
```

Can be read as "Use values in pac where they are not null, otherwise use the values from the calculation", which is exactly what we want. Again we need to access the `.values` for the 'other' (second argument) of the `where` because again the column names aren't the same, but values are aligned.

Do this for each group separately and join them back.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand how your codes work, but it works perfectly with my data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @k.koen, I'm happy to add a bit more of an explanation in the solution if you'd like. Otherwise, perhaps just step through small parts at a time to see what is happening (test things like `pac.mean().div(pdc.mean().values)` and see what it returns. The trickiest part may be [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), though it's a very handy function to use.

Comment: for learning purpose, I would be glad if you would like to explain how it works. Thanks for your further suggestion.